# boost.asio server response hangs when called with apache2-utils

Tags: c++, http, apache2, boost-asio, benchmarking

I'm trying to run benchmark which can be found here: [gitbub asio benchmark](https://github.com/ngrodzitski/test20171219/blob/master/dev/pure_asio/benches/single_handler/main.cpp)

When I run this code as is, I can get a response with RESTED Client in firefox, in fact I can park my finger on the send button and server just keeps sending hello-world-s.

However, when I do:

```
ab -n 1 -v 4 -c 1 http://localhost:8080/
```

apache tools hang, specifically:

```
Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...INFO: GET header == 
--- GET / HTTP/1.0 Host: localhost:8080 
User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3 
Accept: */*


--- LOG: header received: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 12 
Server: Pure asio bench server 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Hello world!

LOG: Response code = 200
```

It seems that response is received, but apache2-utils hang for some reason, I suspect something is wrong with the response, but I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

P.S. it should be noted that it doesn't matter that I've requested only 1 request from the server, if you wait long enough, apache2-utils will report a timeout, which is obviously incorrect, as Firefox gets responses just fine.